# How to move an ImageView along X and Y axis with Sensor Accelerometer Data

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-sensors

I have an oversized image that I want to move up, down, left and right, using the Accelerometer values. I have created the following code that works, but the image moves in distinct steps and does not slide smoothly.

```
float[] matrix = new float[9];
mMatrix.getValues(matrix);

if (accelerometerValues[0] < MOVE_RIGHT_LIMIT) {

 mMatrix.setTranslate(matrix[2] + 10, matrix[5] );
 mSchematicDiagram.setImageMatrix(mMatrix);

 Log.d("PROJECTA_SENSOR", "Moving Right");
```

Is it correct to use the setTranslate on ImageView matrix for this sort of use case and how would you create this smooth transition ?

Answer (score 2):

i'm not sure what kind of image you want to move and why using matrix, but if you have an ImageView, you can do it by setting X and Y values in onSensorChanged method

```
 @Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

        x -= (int) event.values[0];
        y += (int) event.values[1];

        yourImageView.setY(y);
        yourImageView.setX(x);

    }
}
```

Here is my MainActivity code that works well (I just need to add borders, because currently the image can move out of the screen borders), probably it will help somebody.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{

    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor accelerometer;
    private long lastUpdate;

    ImageView mDrawable;
    public static int x = 0;
    public static int y = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDrawable = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

            x -= (int) event.values[0];
            y += (int) event.values[1];

            mDrawable.setY(y);
            mDrawable.setX(x);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
}
```